# How to pull data from other Excel Sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I'm busy designing a Customer accounts sheet, I have all my customer details in individual sheets within the workbook. I Also have some kind of dashboard that I would like to design.

My question is, is there some way I can add an account number, it will do a lookup in all the sheets for the matching account number and pull the necessary fields across without having to do a workbook search.

Example: Dashboard

Account Number `Search Button`

on my Dashboard the following fields

```
Clients Address, Client billing charges, discounts ....
```

on search it will find the matching account number and pull the info into the matching Cells.

any ideas on the best way around this?

This is the Dashboard

I would like to type the account number in and it matches the date on my pricing sheet, and all the Item # and give me the unit Price. 
[image]

Pricing sheet, Row 1 has all the account numbers and column B has all the Item Number codes.
[image]

Thank you

Comment: It would depend on what the sheet names are and how the data is stored. What you would want to do is Loop through the work sheets and then loop through a specific range in the worksheet to determine if it is the correct data. Can you give a sample of your WorkSheet Layout and naming

Comment: Hi @Jean-PierreOosthuizen, I have amended my question

Comment: Is this possible or must I look at another method?

Comment: It is possibly, im just dont have time at the moment to develop something. But try to Loop through the Row 1 looking for the value in your Dashboard Sheet

Comment: I have pasted an answer. It will only insert the INITIAL TAKE-ON COST section of data from the Pricing sheet. I am not sure what you want for the MONTHLY STORAGE COSTS

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add an ActiveX Control Button and name it GenerateInvoiceButton

Then Paste the following into your "DashBoard" Sheet WorkSheet Module

I have indicated with comments where you will need to insert the correct WorkSheet name and cell position

```
 Private Sub GenerateInvoiceButton_Click()

      Dim AccountNumberRange As Range
      Dim AccountColumn As Range
      Dim LastAccountColumn As Long
      Dim AccountDataRange As Range
      Dim DataWS As Worksheet
      Dim DashBoardWS As Worksheet
      Dim AccountNumber As String
      Dim SelectedAccountLastRow As Long
      Dim SpecificAccountDataSet As Range
      Dim DashBoardDataStartPosition As Range

      'Change DataSheet to the sheet name of your sheet with the account data
      Set DataWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DataSheet")

      'Change DashBoardSheet to the sheet name of your sheet with the DashBoard
      Set DashBoardWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DashBoardSheet")

      'This should be set to the cell under the "UnitCost" in the INITIAL TAKE-ON COST section on your DashBoardSheet
      Set DashBoardDataStartPosition = DashBoardWS.Cells(16, "F")

      'This should be the cell in which you insert the account number
      AccountNumber = DashBoardWS.Range("G3").Value

      'Quititng the Code if there is no Account Number
      If AccountNumber = Empty Then

           MsgBox "Please Insert an Account Number"
           End

      End If

      With DataWS
          LastAccountColumn = .Columns(.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
      End With

      'Starting from 4 because your account number start at Column D
      Set AccountNumberRange = DataWS.Range(DataWS.Cells(1, 4), DataWS.Cells(1, LastAccountColumn))

      Set AccountColumn = AccountNumberRange.Find(What:=AccountNumber)

      If AccountColumn Is Nothing Then

           MsgBox "Account Number: " & AccountNumber & _
                  vbCr & vbCr & "Not Found!" & vbCr & _
                  vbCr & _
                  "Please enter a valid Account Number."

      Else

           With DataWS

                SelectedAccountLastRow = .Rows(.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

                'Starting at Row 2 because of your header row
                Set SpecificAccountDataSet = .Range(.Cells(2, AccountColumn.Column), .Cells(SelectedAccountLastRow, AccountColumn.Column))

                SpecificAccountDataSet.Copy

           End With

           DashBoardDataStartPosition.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

      End If

 End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @Jean-Pierre Oosthuizen, thank you for this, Apologies for the late response. This seems to be above my knowledge, I'm missing something. I have added the Active X button, and named it accordingly, but nothing is happening. Any Ideas?

Comment: Checl that design mode is not selected. If design mode is selected then the button will respond like a picture. If you signle click the button what does it do

Comment: Otherwise, add a new button and then double click it to open the VBA screen and then paste the code part of my answer into that Sub. Once again to activate the code you will need to be out of design mode